# Извлечение строк между тэгами регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$str=file_get_contents("http://www.heroeswm.ru/clan_info.php?id=41");
preg_match_all('/(Глава: .*?")/', $str, $name); 
$name = implode("", $name[0]);  echo $name;
```

Данный скрипт выводит со страницы всю инфу от "Глава" до "Протокол". Мне же нужно, чтобы вывело только ник Глава. То есть чтобы пропарсило от "Глава" и до конца ника самого Главы. Как исправить? Я так понял, что изменить требует только строку:

```
preg_match_all('/(Глава: .*?")/', $str, $name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<b>Глава: </b>
  <a class="pi" href="pl_info.php?id=4598">Игнациус</a>

preg_match_all('/<b>\s*Глава:\s*.*?<\/a>/gi', $str, $name);
```

Comment: Модификатора /g в php нету ;) для этого служит preg_match_all

Comment: Да, промахнулся. Там точно был какой-то модификатор для мультистрокового поиска. m?